# ¿Porqué no funciona mi spinner en Android Studio?

Tags: android

Mi aplicativo usa Cloud Firestore, y para el realizar la actualizacion de datos, traigo los datos del Cloud. Pero el problema fue con el spinner. Intenté con este metodo:

```
for (int i=0; i<Nom_UniA.size();i++){
    if (nomuni.equals(Nom_UniA.get(i))){
        spinner.setSelection(i);
    }
}
```

`nomuni` es el `String` que se obtiene de la bd del valor que quiero ver en el spinner. Entonces `Nom_UniA`, es el spinner y recorro todo el spinner hasta encontrar similitud y colocar la posición en donde lo necesito.
**El problema es que a veces funciona y a veces no. No sé a que se deba pero a la hora de hacer el debug, en algunas ocasiones se salta todo el `for` y en otras lo recorre**. Obviamente cuando lo recorre sí funciona, pero cuando se lo salta pues da el primer valor por defecto. No sé a qué se deba pero porfa necesito ayuda con eso.

Comment: Si a veces se salta el `for`, ¿no será porque el `size` de `Nom_UniA` es `0` en esos casos?

Comment: No se me había ocurrido, muchas gracias.