# Array no se llena correctamente Android studio

Tags: java, android, array, spinner

Tengo un array que lo lleno de la siguiente forma. El NomArtA

```
ArrayList<String> Nom_ArtA = new ArrayList<String>();

final List<Articulos> articulos = new ArrayList<>();
    db.collection("Articulos").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                for (final QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                    String Nom_Art = (String) document.getData().get("Nom_Art");
                           Nom_ArtA.add(Nom_Art);
                    String Nom_Uni = (String) document.getData().get("Nom_Uni");
                           Nom_UniA.add(Nom_Uni);
                    Double Pre_Art = (Double) document.getData().get("Pre_Art");
                           Pre_ArtA.add(Pre_Art);
                    articulos.add(new Articulos(Nom_Art,Nom_Uni));
                    ArrayAdapter<Articulos> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(updateVen.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, articulos);
                    spinnerv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }}}});}
```

El codigo es para poblar los valores de un spinner, aparte de recuperarlos, guardo el valor en el array mencionado definido global y en algunas ocasiones, sin motivo aparente el array me lo considera vacio, como podrian entender en una preguna anterior que hice: [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/423956/porqu%C3%A9-no-funciona-mi-spinner-en-android-studio?noredirect=1#comment757175_423956).
Quisiera porfavor que me ayuden con alguna idea, sugerencia o critica para entender el motivo del error.

**Esto es lo que muesta el debug, no adiciona el double en el array double**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Existe más de 1 hilo que realice operaciones I/O sobre tu arraylist? En ese caso, hay que sincronizar su uso

Comment: la foto q muestra es junto cuando estas en ese paso cuando recien lo añade por eso sale 0 muestra despues o cuando este en adapter. Trata de mostrar en consola el valor del double. y de tu resultado tu json

Comment: @OsAndNoTi; el problema es con los array Nom_ArtA, Nom_UniA y PreArtA ya que no los llena, en la imagen se muestra cuando ya ejecutó `Pre_ArtA.add(Pre_Art);` y se ve en la consola como el valor Pre_Art tiene de valor "40" que es el valor que se colocará em Pre_ArtA pero no lo introduce porque se ve que tiene de tamaño 0